# Specify Excel 'Display Format' while importing data

Tags: excel

I'm currently using an excel document as a template for generating a report. This is done by first specifying an 'Xml Map' in Excel and then importing data against it. The report generation works fine.

The problem is that I want the display format on the cell to be 'General' and not 'Text' after the import. I came across this link (yes, Excel 2007)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/xml-schema-definition-xsd-data-type-support-HP010206414.aspx#BMxsdexport

The link specifies that Excel will set string data from the xml import to display as 'Text' by default. I need this to be displayed as 'General' instead. Is there a way to do this?

The only solution I've come up with so far is to use a macro to change the display format after opening the document but if I can do it using only Excel settings it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping cannot be changed.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdf99171-0a53-4716-9e72-25afc36ddf90/specify-excel-display-format-while-importing-data

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the text import feature:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx
NOTE:  the important step that should address your need is the "Column data format" section, which often gets overlooked as it is the last step of the import.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I should have mentioned the import is doing through code. Only the completed report is sent to the user.